# System not booting up on replacing cmoss battery

Tags: hp-proliant, boot

I have HP ProLiant dl360 Gen 7 server, after I replaced cmoss battery I am seeing blue screen. Please let me know if anything needs to be done on replacing the cmoss battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a System Maintenance Switch for your model, configure it to reset "to defaults". I had similar issue once, BIOS won't reset via menu.